# How to set Source Control plug-in (VS2P4) persistently?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have following Source Control plug-ins in list of *Options->Source Control->Plug-in Selection*:
* None
* Visual Studio Team Foundation Server
* VS2P4

**It works for current session** to select *VS2P4* and set its connection to *Use P4Config instead*.
But after VisualStudio restart the selection is reverted to *None*.

How can I **persistently** set *VS2P4* and *Use P4Config instead*?
I do not need *Visual Studio Team Foundation Server*, so if it is possible to remove it from list I could do it.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in VS2P4 that has been fixed in a later release.

Comment: An upgrade fixed it. Thank you. I had version 1.60 before upgrade.

Comment: No it doesn't work. VS2P4 is still set after VS restart. But after loading a solution the provider is set to *Perforce SCM* (in meantime I have installed "Perforce SCM" and "P4VS", too).

Comment: I give it up. VS2P4 is so bugy, I can't believe it. Now it (version 1.85) does not show any glyphs after opening solution.

Comment: I have the same problems with P4VS extension.  And now I have installed p4scc (version 121.55.8565) and this works.

Answer (score 0):

You may have bindings in the solution. If there is a 'source control' item in the File menu, try the 'Change Source Control' option